After the latest update of VSCode, my TSX code started throwing errors

The Vue code runs and builds without any issues, but it does show an error. Colleagues who haven't updated VSCode don't encounter this error, but those who have updated do.

Importing Fragment from Vue can solve the issue, but since the codebase is large and every file needs to be updated, it's very troublesome. I suspect that the stricter syntax enforcement in the TypeScript JSX compiler after the VSCode update is causing this. Is there a way to change the local settings to modify this uniformly?

This might be the rule? https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#jsxFragmentFactory
